# Configuring SAML for on prem Sites 9.1 CME but getting a 405

Tags: sites-9.1

We are working on configuring SAML to Azure AD for an on-prem Sites 9.1 Content Management.  We are able to authenticate against the Azure AD Identities, but when the response comes through, there is  a POST verb, and that is not allowed by the main CME UI landing page.  And we can see a "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed." error on the page, instead of the main landing page body.  I am wondering if there is a different URL we are supposed to be using for the Assertion Consumer Service URL.

Comment: It is hard to understand what is going wrong and why without seeing the entire authentication flow (HAR file).  I would recommend to contact RWS Customer Support for this.